# typescript: relative modules were not found

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

I am converting code from javascript to typescript as a part of a migration process.
I need to import 'xyz.css' file in my another file like 'abc.ts'. both the files are in the same directory. I am importing the file as follows :

```
import '../../xyz.css';
```

and it gives me an error : 
relative modules were not found:

```
'../../../xyz.css' in '../../dist/abc.js'
```

This error occurs while webpack compilation process.
Please give a suggestion to resolve same. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For non-node_modules based modules, you should use a path, usually a relative path. So if you're trying to reference xyz.css from the same directory as your typescript file, you would use
    import './xyz.css';